# org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo leaks memory in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, groovy, memory-leaks

- `org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo` leaks memory in Spring Boot
- Prints the following message in the Log
- The class `org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo`, loaded by
  `org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader @ 0x4001e7bb0`,
  occupies 2,155,637,272 (64.28%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in
  class `org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo`, loaded by
  `org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader @
  0x4001e7bb0`
- Any clue of what is going wrong here?

Comment: I have a hard time finding the question in this?  Do you want confirmation, so you can file a bug report?

Comment: Updated the questions with the ask